Does this transformer look like the secondary winding can be easily unwound to change the output voltage?
Similar to this post: How to bring down the output voltage of a 2 x 25 VAC 6 A transformer? (Around 35 VDC after rectifiers) I want to bring down the voltage of this low profile transformer. Does the secondary look like it can easily be unwound? It's a 100/17 VAC that I want to convert to 120/17 VAC. Any other considerations?
I presume I would need to unwind 20% of the secondary(s).
Thanks for any help!

The device maxes out at about 20 watts/20 VA consumption (labelled 100 V/16 watt), which already exceeds the transformer, so I guess I cannot remove a primary.

probably not ... but it depends on what you mean by easily

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The device this was made for the Japanese market, i.e. 100vac. Here line voltage is 120vac, which means the secondary is now 17vac x 1.2 = 20.4vac, which will probably damage the rest of the circuitry (there is a rectifier bridge following this for DC.)

As far as defining easily :-) I am reasonable handy, and can remove the transformer, the kapton tape, etc. Just not sure about unwinding the wire, if it's shellacked in, for example.

What I don't want to do is wreck the transformer so the thing becomes unusable.

Is your main point to supply some load with a lower voltage/ same voltage where the input is higher? Or is it to keep using this very transformer? Or to learn generally how to modify a single phase transformer to operate at a higher voltage? (Resgarding saturation, you're perfectly fine going from 100 V, 50 Hz to 120 V, 60 Hz.)

Chances are there is one each primary (my guess: 100 V…120 V) and secondary (17 V…20 V? 8.5 to 10?) winding on each coil former.
If there were 17 V secondary windings and you only needed up to 6 VA, you could put one of the secondaries in series to the parallel primaries: 117 ≈ 120.

I think I am out of luck, the secondary's are already in series; I measured each secondary as 1.1 ohms, but the output wires are 2.2.

I would need to unwind both secondary's, and the primary's are underneath that, I  believe.

(See my comment to the question: reasonable handling depends on your goal - explicitly mention it in the question body.)(Complete rewinding most probably is not your best option.)

Two make it so flat, there are two primary's and two secondary's each in series.

(Why put this comment under my "answer"? It's pretty much what I suggested, if I didn't offer a guess about secondaries being parallel or in series.)(no apostrophe there: ~ies)

sorry, just put these thoughts in the easiest way. no insult meant.

(No offence taken. Why not put that information in the question body?)
